# Python, ctypes, multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-3.x, structure, ctypes

I have structure in Python code and in C code. I fill these fields

```
("bones_pos_vect",((c_float*4)*30)),
("bones_rot_quat",((c_float*4)*30))
```

in python code with the right values, but when I request them in C code, I get only 0.0 from all array cells. Why do I lose the values? All other fields of my structures work fine.

```
class SceneObject(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x_coord", c_float),
                ("y_coord", c_float),
                ("z_coord", c_float),
                ("x_angle", c_float),
                ("y_angle", c_float),
                ("z_angle", c_float),
                ("indexes_count", c_int),
                ("vertices_buffer", c_uint),
                ("indexes_buffer", c_uint),
                ("texture_buffer", c_uint),
                ("bones_pos_vect",((c_float*4)*30)),
                ("bones_rot_quat",((c_float*4)*30))]

typedef struct
{
    float x_coord;
    float y_coord;
    float z_coord;
    float x_angle;
    float y_angle;
    float z_angle;
    int indexes_count;
    unsigned int vertices_buffer;
    unsigned int indexes_buffer;
    unsigned int texture_buffer;
    float bones_pos_vect[30][4];
    float bones_rot_quat[30][4];    
} SceneObject;
```

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are not mapped one to one in memory in c. Thus float[30][4] is actually an array (size=30) of float pointers (pointing to the beginning of the float array). The (c_float*4)*30) might be really a array of arrays (first 4 floats then the second 4 floats etc.) though. You should test that out.

Comment: So, I must send simply (c_float*(4*30))?

Comment: no i think it should be POINTER(c_float)*30; use `[i]` to access the single values then. e.g `pbase = bones_pos_vect[17]`; `p = pbase[3] #third float in array`; `value = p.contents`

Comment: No it's not working, i get only 0.0. Also, I tryed use (c_float*(4*30) and have same result((( i want to cry, cause it's not workin

Comment: and i want to send values to C code

Comment: if you iterate over the array after you filled it does it prints the correct values?

Comment: yes but only in C code, in python all good

Comment: @Paranaix, `float[30][4]` is not an array of float pointers.  @shestakoffvs has the correct definition.

Comment: @shestakoffvs You must have a mistake in either your Python code calling C or in the C code displaying the array.  Your definition is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can use a multidimensional array with Python and ctypes.

I wrote the following C code, and used `gcc` in MinGW to compile this to `slib.dll`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct TestStruct {
    int     a;
    float   array[30][4];
} TestStruct;

extern void print_struct(TestStruct *ts) {
    int i,j;
    for (j = 0; j < 30; ++j) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            printf("%g ", ts->array[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note that the struct contains a 'two-dimensional' array.

I then wrote the following Python script:

```
from ctypes import *

class TestStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int),
                ("array", (c_float * 4) * 30)]

slib = CDLL("slib.dll")
slib.print_struct.argtypes = [POINTER(TestStruct)]
slib.print_struct.restype = None

t = TestStruct()

for i in range(30):
    for j in range(4):
        t.array[i][j] = i + 0.1*j

slib.print_struct(byref(t))
```

When I ran the Python script, it called the C function, which printed out the contents of the multidimensional array:

```
C:\>slib.py
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4
3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4
4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4
5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4
... rest of output omitted
```

I've used Python 2, whereas the tags on your question indicate that you're using Python 3.  However, I don't believe this should make a difference.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it.  I wrote basically the same code with the OP's structure and definition.

Comment: Oh guys, i'm so stupid))) And big thx for example code, with it i'm understand what wrong with my)))) insted of assign to every varing in structure field array i just assigned it whole new array: scene_object.bones_pos_vects = import_content["bones_pos_vects"] now i do this so: for n in range(len(import_content["bones_pos_vects"])):
            for u in range(3):
                scene_object.bones_pos_vects[n][u] = import_content["bones_pos_vects"][n][u]
                scene_object.bones_rot_quats[n][u] = import_content["bones_rot_quats"][n][u]  Now all work very well))) big thx)))

Answer (score 0):

*Here i hava pass two 2d numpy array and print value of one array for the reference*

you can use this and write **multidimensional** array

`cpp_function.cpp`

compile it using : `g++ -shared -fPIC cpp_function.cpp -o cpp_function.so`

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
void mult_matrix(double *a1, double *a2, size_t a1_h, size_t a1_w, 
                  size_t a2_h, size_t a2_w, int size)
{
    //std::cout << "a1_h & a1_w" << a1_h << a1_w << std::endl; 
    //std::cout << "a2_h & a2_w" << a2_h << a2_w << std::endl; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a1_h; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < a1_w; j++) {
            printf("%f ", a1[i * a1_h + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

Python File
`main.py`

```
import ctypes
import numpy
from time import time

libmatmult = ctypes.CDLL("./cpp_function.so")
ND_POINTER_1 = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, 
                                      ndim=2,
                                      flags="C")
ND_POINTER_2 = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, 
                                    ndim=2,
                                    flags="C")
libmatmult.mult_matrix.argtypes = [ND_POINTER_1, ND_POINTER_2, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t]
# print("-->", ctypes.c_size_t)

def mult_matrix_cpp(a,b):
    shape = a.shape[0] * a.shape[1]
    libmatmult.mult_matrix.restype = None
    libmatmult.mult_matrix(a, b, *a.shape, *b.shape , a.shape[0] * a.shape[1])

size_a = (300,300)
size_b = size_a

a = numpy.random.uniform(low=1, high=255, size=size_a)
b = numpy.random.uniform(low=1, high=255, size=size_b)

t2 = time()
out_cpp = mult_matrix_cpp(a,b)
print("cpp time taken:{:.2f} ms".format((time() - t2) * 1000))
out_cpp = numpy.array(out_cpp).reshape(size_a[0], size_a[1])
```