# ctypes error on com client

Tags: python, com, ctypes

I am trying to create a com client to send messages to a server. I have the ole viewer definitions and created the structures(classes) in python, that are used to construct a complex structure that has more structures and enums in it.

Everything seems to be going well, but when i try to pass a SampleObject* to the client call, i get this error :

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:
expected LP__SampleObject instance instead of LP__SampleObject
```

Which seems pretty weird. What i am doing is something like(this is where i get the error) :

```
dialog = _SampleObject('hello', struct1, 'hi_there', struct2, 1, struct3, 1, 1, 1, 'me', 'you', 'him')
obj.COM_function( pointer(dialog) )
```

I've tried many things, but cannot get around that error. Any ideas ?

*(obj is just a cc.CreateObject() coclass object, which works with no problems)*

I really can't see the problem, even the comtype definition displays that in the interface :

```
( ['in'], POINTER(_SampleObject), 'pAction' ),
```

which fits perfectly with pointer(dialog). This is a very weird error, could it be a but on comtypes ?

Comment: how did you setup COM_function.argtypes?

Comment: I haven't. Should i do something with that ? I will take a look at it now. Please note that the server is kind of a grey box to me. I only know the IDL based on ole viewer, and it shows _SampleObject* as [in].

Comment: @JeremyBrown : Could you please give me an idea of what argtypes should look like in this occasion, and how they are supposed to be set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you defining the `ctypes` structs and unions of your arguments more than once?

If you define a `Structure` or `Union` subclass, use it in the `argtypes` of a C library function, redefine the structure or union and then attempt to pass an instance of the redefined class to the C function, you will get an error similar to the one you're seeing.

I took the code I used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11385138) and added a (completely unnecessary) redefinition of the structure used with it. (I also changed the `byref` at the end to `pointer` - using `byref` gives you a different error message.)  The Python code ended up as follows:

```
from ctypes import *

class TestStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int),
                ("array", (c_float * 4) * 30)]

slib = CDLL("slib.dll")
slib.print_struct.argtypes = [POINTER(TestStruct)]
slib.print_struct.restype = None

# Redefine the ctypes structure.
class TestStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int),
                ("array", (c_float * 4) * 30)]

t = TestStruct()

for i in range(30):
    for j in range(4):
        t.array[i][j] = i + 0.1*j

slib.print_struct(pointer(t))
```

When I ran this modified script, I got the following output:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff>slib2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Python stuff\slib2.py", line 21, in <module>
    slib.print_struct(pointer(t))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_TestStruct instance instead of LP_TestStruct
```

Comment: Hey Luke Woodward, thank you for the very interesting answer. The error that you are getting is pretty much what i am getting as well, but _SampleObject is defined only once in my code. However, i am not that sure on whether the comtypes.gen definition would play any role in that. I have something like 'import comtypes.gen.SampleObjectLib as SampleObjectLib' in my code, that pretty much gives me an interface to the lib. If i remove my definitions though, i get 'undefined errors' when trying to create the actual pointer(dialog). Very interesting though, i will check it more, +1.

Comment: I see that the SampleObjectLib points to a {CLSID}.py file that does indeed contain these definitions again. However, i don't see that they are included in my code, since directly invoking them yields an undefined error. Hmm, weird, i will thoroughly check, it seems that what you are saying is probably the reason why it happens, somehow. But it seems very likely.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never worked with COM before; all I could really do was to come up with some way of reproducing the error message.  Good luck in tracking down the problem, it looks like you're making progress. :)

Comment: Actually it worked :) Removed the definitions and updated some imports and worked great ! You really saved my day, thanx !