# Python ctypes: calling a function with custom types in c

Tags: python, c, arrays, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm trying to wrap [pre-existing c code](https://github.com/wjasper/Linux_Drivers) for use in Python in Linux. I have little experience with c, and I'm currently approaching this problem using ctypes. My C function requires a 2d array with custom type entries and I don't know how to recreate this in python to pass it to the c function.

Here is the function I'm attempting to call:

```
void usbBuildGainTableAI_USB1808(libusb_device_handle *udev, Calibration_AIN table[NCHAN_1808][NGAINS_1808])
{

  int i, j;
  uint16_t address = 0x7000;  // base address of ADC calibration coefficients.

  for (i = 0; i < NCHAN_1808; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NGAINS_1808; j++) {
      usbMemAddressW_USB1808(udev, address);
      usbMemoryR_USB1808(udev, (uint8_t *) &table[i][j].slope, sizeof(float));
      address += 4;
      usbMemAddressW_USB1808(udev, address);
      usbMemoryR_USB1808(udev, (uint8_t *) &table[i][j].offset, sizeof(float));
      address += 4;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

The header file has defined

```
typedef struct Calibration_AIN_t {
  float slope;
  float offset;
} Calibration_AIN;
```

where NCHAN_18081 and NGAINS_1808 are constants and udev is an integer. I've followed an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384015/python-ctypes-multi-dimensional-array) regarding multidimensional arrays and attempted to make a structure like the one in the c code.

```
_1808 = CDLL(os.path.abspath("lib1808.so"))

NCHAN_1808 = 8  # max number of A/D channels in the device
NGAINS_1808 = 4  # max number of gain levels

class Calibration_AIN(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("slope", c_float), ("offset", c_float)]

class AINarray(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("array", (Calibration_AIN() * NCHAN_1808) * NGAINS_1808)]

table_AIN = AINarray()

_1808.usbBuildGainTableAI_USB1808(udev, table_AIN)
```

But there's a couple problems with this: the custom type Calibration_AIN can't be populated in an array with the operator * like an int or float can, and I can't pass a custom type through to c. I've also tried making the array with a list of lists in Python, but I can't convert that to anything useful to c passable through ctypes.

How can I call this function from python without modifying the c code? Any help would be much appreciated, and also let me know if I should just learn c and try to write my program in c or Cython. Ctypes may not be the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
_fields_ = [("array", (Calibration_AIN() * NCHAN_1808) * NGAINS_1808)]
```

should raise a *TypeError*, since you **instantiate** *Calibration_AIN*. I believe that what you meant was:

```
_fields_ = [("array", (Calibration_AIN * NCHAN_1808) * NGAINS_1808)]
```

But even so, you don't need the *AINarray* wrapper. According to [[Python]: Arrays](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#arrays), you could do something like:

```
Calibration_AIN_Table = (Calibration_AIN * NCHAN_1808) * NGAINS_1808
```

and then, in order to initialize an instance do smth like:

> ```
> >>> cat = Calibration_AIN_Table()
> >>> for i in range(NGAINS_1808):
> ...     for j in range(NCHAN_1808):
> ...         cat[i][j].slope = i * j
> ...         cat[i][j].offset = i * i * j
> ...
> >>> cat[2][3].slope
> 6.0
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do this I get an error on the line `cat[i][j].slope = i * j` `TypeError: _cytpes.PyCArrayType object does not support indexing`

Comment: `cat = Calibration_AIN_Table()`, `cat` should be an **instance** note the `()` after `Calibration_AIN_Table`.